# How do I show a pop up only once?

Tags: javascript, popup

my pop up seems to show to my website visitors even if they've hidden the pop up or subscribed previously.

How can I change the following code to only show the pop up once?

```
setTimeout(function(){
        var newsletterModal = $('#newsletterModal');
        if (newsletterModal.length && typeof $.cookie('newsletter_modal') === 'undefined') {
        if ($.cookie('age_verified') || !$('#verifyAgeModal').length) {
            newsletterModal.foundation('open');
            $.cookie('newsletter_modal', true, { path: '/' });
        }
        else {
            verifyAgeModal.on('closed.zf.reveal', function() {
                newsletterModal.foundation('open');
                $.cookie('newsletter_modal', true, { path: '/' });
            });
        }
    }
}, 20000);
```

I don't use the age verification facility, but I haven't tried removing it in case I opt to include age verification later on.

As a separate question, is there a way to distinguish between those who have hidden the pop up and those who have subscribed (with the aim of re-showing the pop up to non-subscribers a month or so later)?

Answer (score 0):

I can do it by combining with ajax which will save the status of the dialog box in the database. On click of close button, perform ajax request to save view status as 1 or done. In the next loading check view status before displaying the modal.

How to identify the user who viewed the dialog box - save unique identifier in the cookie which will be used for as identifying browser log events.